# How to combine Analyzer instances for stop word removal and stemming in Lucene (5.2.1)?

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, stemming, stop-words

I'm using **Lucene** latest version **5.2.1**.. While indexing the documents I want the stop words to be removed after that all the words should be stemmed to its root word.

There is ***EnglishAnalyzer*** available but **stemming is not accurate**. And there is **StopAnalyzer** which removes the stop words.

***Do Lucene have any analyzer which does the both things ?***

And I had written one custom analyzer for the purpose of **Stemming using KStemFilter**. ***How can I use existing StopAnalyzer in the custom analyzer***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to combine different analyzers in Lucene together.

You should use something like this:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(text);
Tokenizer whitespaceTokenizer = new WhitespaceTokenizer();
whitespaceTokenizer.setReader(reader);
TokenStream tokenStream = new StopFilter(whitespaceTokenizer, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
tokenStream = new PorterStemFilter(tokenStream);
```

where **text** is a variable, containing something you want to be analyzed. Here I combine whitespace tokenization (probably you could replace it with **StandardAnalyzer** which is more sophisticated) and then I remove stop words with **StopFilter** and later in analyzer chain use a **PorterStemFilter** (which also more better than just simple **EnglishStemmer**, also you could replace it with any **TokenFilter** you like.

Complete example is available here - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/master/lucene4/src/main/java/org/mystic/StopWordsStemmingAnalyzer.java

Comment: Thanks Mysterion. If I put this logic in a custom class which extends Analyzer, and putting this Analyzer into IndexWriterConfig then how token stream reset/close will be called ?

Comment: i guess it's another question :) also, if you will take a look at my java code, you could see, that reset/close could be called by you, if I understand your question correctly

Comment: yeah its another question.  The same logic if I want to put it in a custom analyzer which extends Analyzer abstract class, then how it can be done? This logic need to put in createComponents(String a) right.

Comment: Thanks Mysterion. Referred the documentation for my another question in the comment and your answer directed to the solution.

Comment: the example is not available anymore.. is there another link ?